# How to write objects directly into packfiles using libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I have a tool that effectively builds up a git repository. I'm currently using functions like `git_commit_create` and the treebuilder to build up the commits, but the objects always get written into loose objects instead of a packfile. I tried using the approach described at https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/4090#issuecomment-274748061 - creating a new odb, adding a pack backend, and setting that as the odb for the repository, but it fails when writing with the following error:

```
cannot write object - unsupported in the loaded odb backends
```

It's unclear to me how to go about making this work. It seems like it should be possible to have the API just write all the new objects directly into packfiles.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the way to do this is to use a mempack backend. Roughly:

- `git_mempack_new` to get a new mempack backend
- `git_odb_add_backend` to add it to the odb. Use a high priority value so that the mempack is the one chosen for writing
- Do the writes to the repo
- `git_mempack_dump` into a buf
- Then use a packwriter to write the buf as a pack.